# I'm trying to get mlab data into console using node.js but getting this error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs, mongojs

I'm following this youtube video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFP0oXNNveg&t=460s .i did the same as he did even i changed the code according to present update by searching  in google(the errors which i got when i'm trying to update).

Please help me out with this problem!!!

Error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/tasks 404 (Not Found)    zone.js:2969
scheduleTask    @   zone.js:2969
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:407
onScheduleTask  @   zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @   zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone    @   zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @   zone.js:3001
proto.(anonymous function)  @   zone.js:1394
(anonymous) @   http.js:1103
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe  @   Observable.js:42
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:28
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call   @   map.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:23
TasksComponent  @   tasks.component.ts:11
createClass @   core.js:9301
createDirectiveInstance @   core.js:9186
createViewNodes @   core.js:10406
callViewAction  @   core.js:10722
execComponentViewsAction    @   core.js:10641
createViewNodes @   core.js:10434
createRootView  @   core.js:10320
callWithDebugContext    @   core.js:11351
debugCreateRootView @   core.js:10838
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create    @   core.js:8666
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create    @   core.js:3315
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.bootstrap    @   core.js:4550
(anonymous) @   core.js:4358
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap  @   core.js:4358
(anonymous) @   core.js:4324
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:388
onInvoke    @   core.js:3824
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run   @   zone.js:138
(anonymous) @   zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask    @   zone.js:421
onInvokeTask    @   core.js:3815
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask    @   zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask   @   zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @   zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)        
scheduleMicroTask   @   zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @   zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @   zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then   @   zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @   core.js:4353
./src/main.ts   @   main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:76
0   @   main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules    @   bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback    @   bootstrap:30
(anonymous)

ERROR Response  core.js:1673 
 {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta char…<pre>Cannot GET /api/tasks</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}headers: Headers {_headers: Map(10), _normalizedNames: Map(10)}_headers: Map(10) {"content-security-policy" => Array(1), "x-content-type-options" => Array(1), "x-powered-by" => Array(1), "allow" => Array(1), "access-control-allow-methods" => Array(1), …}_normalizedNames: Map(10) {"content-security-policy" => "content-security-policy", "x-content-type-options" => "x-content-type-options", "x-powered-by" => "x-powered-by", "allow" => "allow", "access-control-allow-methods" => "access-control-allow-methods", …}__proto__: Objectok: falsestatus: 404statusText: "Not Found"type: 2url: "http://localhost:3000/api/tasks"_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot GET /api/tasks</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"__proto__: Bodyconstructor: ƒ Response(responseOptions)toString: ƒ ()__proto__: Object
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1673
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1719
next @ core.js:4319
schedulerFn @ core.js:3555
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:209
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:147
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:55
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3539
(anonymous) @ core.js:3846
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3783
onHandleError @ core.js:3846
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:392
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:191
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:485
timer @ zone.js:2054
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2075
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2090
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
hostReportError @ hostReportError.js:3
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:181
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:83
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:61
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:83
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:61
onLoad @ http.js:1059
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:3815
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
error (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone.js:1666
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleEventTask @ zone.js:258
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1831
(anonymous) @ http.js:1102
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:28
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:23
TasksComponent @ tasks.component.ts:11
createClass @ core.js:9301
createDirectiveInstance @ core.js:9186
createViewNodes @ core.js:10406
callViewAction @ core.js:10722
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:10641
createViewNodes @ core.js:10434
createRootView @ core.js:10320
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:11351
debugCreateRootView @ core.js:10838
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create @ core.js:8666
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create @ core.js:3315
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.bootstrap @ core.js:4550
(anonymous) @ core.js:4358
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap @ core.js:4358
(anonymous) @ core.js:4324
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:3824
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:3815
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4353
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

Back-End
Packet.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = 3000;
var index = require('./routes/index');
var tasks = require('./routes/tasks');

var app = express();

//view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

//Body parser Metaware

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', tasks);

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("server started at port "+port)
})
```

route-> index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('index.html');

});

module.exports = router;
```

route->tasks.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs =require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://Revanth:revanth99@ds161790.mlab.com:61790/revanth', ['tasks']);

//GET All Tasks
router.get('/tasks', function(req, res, next){
    db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(tasks);
    });

});
//GET Single task
router.get('/task/:id',function(req, res, next){
    db.tasks.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function(err, task){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(task);
    });
});

//Save Task
router.post('/task', function(res, req, next){
    var task = req.body;
    if(!task.title || (task.isDone + '')){
        res.statusCode(404);
        res.json({
            "error": "Bad Data"
        });
    } else{
        db.tasks.save(task, function(err, task){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }
            ress.json(task);
        })
    }
});

//Delete Task
router.delete('/task/:id',function(req, res, next){
    db.tasks.remove({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function(err, task){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(task);
    });
});

//Update Task
router.put('/task/:id',function(req, res, next){
    var task = req.body;
    var updTask = {};

    if(task.isDone){
        updTask.isDone = task.isDone;
    }

    if(task.title){
        update.title = task.title;
    }
    if(!update){
        res.status(400);
        res.json({
            "error": "Bad Data"
        });
    } else{
        db.tasks.update({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)},updTask, {}, function(err, task){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(task);
        });
    }


});



module.exports = router;
```

Front-END
app->Component->tasks->tasks.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from '../../services/task.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'tasks',
  templateUrl: './tasks.component.html'
})

export class TasksComponent {
    constructor(private taskService:TaskService){
            this.taskService.getTasks()
                .subscribe(tasks => {
                    console.log(tasks);
                });
    }
}
```

app->services->task.service.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from '../../services/task.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'tasks',
  templateUrl: './tasks.component.html'
})

export class TasksComponent {
    constructor(private taskService:TaskService){
            this.taskService.getTasks()
                .subscribe(tasks => {
                    console.log(tasks);
                });
    }
}
```

apps->app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from './services/task.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers:[ TaskService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'client';
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from'@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TasksComponent } from './components/tasks/tasks.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TasksComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You have pasted same code for component and service

Comment: Did you start the node server? It looks like your angular client does not find the endpoint `GET http://localhost:3000/api/tasks`

Comment: yaah, I started the server

Comment: ohh sorry & thank you Sajeetharan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first of all need to identify where exactly the problem could be.Try using postman using the right http verbs to call on your api endpoints.ensure that the server is running and the endpoints are correct as defined in the routes.try to log the data that u have queried from db in the console.`console.log(task) or logging the error`that way you can know where exactly the problem could be and ask/solve accordingly